# Why can't I do this in a function?

Tags: javascript

```
function focus(element) {
    document.form.element.focus();
}
```

I want to have a function to focus on an input box, but it seems I can't do that. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So it’s an *HTMLElement* object?

Comment: Actually, you know what? I just realized I didn't even need the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're passing `element` directly to the function, call `focus` directly on that.

```
function focus(element) {
    element.focus();
}
```

If you're just passing the name of the element to the function, then ..

```
function focus(element) {
    document.form[element].focus();
}
```